# How to copy just the information in the second place of a Column in R with several information

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a file like this with these two situations, but with much more information:

```
Animal  Column.2
1       0000000000000082 Y001003014
2       0000000000000195 TU00000186 REID:n05510451964756
3       0000000000000104 F001002923 F001002923
```

My column 2 has multiple information, but I want just the second information, like this:

```
 Animal  Column.2
    1    Y001003014
    2    TU00000186
    3    F001002923
```

I tried this code :

```
df$Column.2= gsub("^.{0,17}" & '.{11}$', '', df$Column.2)
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[^ ]+?` takes everything until the first space, `([^ ]+?)\\b` takes the second element until a word boundary `\\b` and `.*` takes the rest. With `\\1` you paste in what you get from `([^ ]+?)`.

```
(df$Column.2 <- sub("^[^ ]+? ([^ ]+?)\\b.*", "\\1" ,df$Column.2))
#[1] "Y001003014" "TU00000186" "F001002923"
```

In case the format is fixed you can use:

```
sub("^.{17}(.{10}).*", "\\1" ,df$Column.2)
#[1] "Y001003014" "TU00000186" "F001002923"
```

where `^.{17}` takes the first 17 characters, `(.{10})` takes the flowing 10 characters and stores them in `\\1` and `.*` takes the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use regular expression, since elements are separated by spaces, you can split the string using spaces as separators

```
df = data.frame(Animal = c(1:3),
                Column.2=c("0000000000000082 Y001003014",
                           "0000000000000195 TU00000186 REID:n05510451964756",
                           "0000000000000104 F001002923 F001002923"
                           )
                )
```

and then using [`strsplit`](http://rfunction.com/archives/1499)  and `lapply` as follows (note you must `unlist` the result)

```
unlist(lapply(df$Column.2, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " ", fixed=FALSE))[2]))
```

getting this result

```
[1] "Y001003014" "TU00000186" "F001002923"
```